# Candy Machine Mints Happening Automatically During Sugar Upload

Tags: solana, nft, metaplex, candy-machine, solana-cli

I haven't seen this before: I was just doing an NFT upload using the Sugar CLI. Everything went fine but at the end of the upload I saw this:

```
[2/2] Verification
Verifying 2000 config line(s): (Ctrl+C to abort)
[00:00:35] Config line verification successful ███████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████ 2000/2000

An item has already been minted. Skipping candy machine collection verification...

Verification successful. You're good to go!
```

I noticed this line: `An item has already been minted. Skipping candy machine collection verification`

Then when I went to the upload URL it said 17 had already been minted:

See your candy machine at:
-> https://www.solaneyes.com/address/xxx?cluster=mainnet

Then when I went to load the project on my `localhost` the minted number kept climbing, now it's at 214/2000 and this is without the site live on the web at all.

I'm wondering if this is a glitch that will correct itself sometime this evening or could this be a bot that is minting things?

The initial WL price is `0` and I did set the go-live date as `now` just for the upload and then I go in and change the date manually in the config after the upload is completed. I've done it this way in the past. Since I've set the go-live date to the future the minting has stopped.

Any ideas on the cause of this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bots detected your new candy machine and minted from it since it was already live. If the mint is cheap / for free there will always be bots that mint.

Solution is to simply set the go live date into the future and not `now`.

Comment: Yea that's what I figured. Didn't realize they could get to it that fast. But I'll start the upload process over then to a brand new candy machine.